# Avoid downloading node JS modules over and over for all projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm

I am learning NodeJS and Electron app dev and currently every sample app I work on has me run the command `npm install` which results in the node_modules downloading to the project folder.  This results in a really large amount of disk usage as many app use the same node modules over and over.

Is there a way to install all the required node modules for all projects to a central location and make them all use that 1 source of modules?

---

### UPDATE

Another concern of mine.  If the Electron apps I am building are packaged as an install-able .exe file.  Will they be able to package the functionality needed from those global Node packages wwhen the app is ran on another users PC?

Comment: https://bower.io/

Comment: @Davidlrnt I just tested running `bower install jquery` on 2 separate Electron project folders and bother folders ended up downloading a copy of jQuery.js.  Is there a way to make it global.  1 install per library to be used by any app?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to install npm packages: locally or globally.
To download packages globally, you simply use the command `npm install -g` 
This is recommended if you want to use module as a command line tool.

---

## UPDATE

You can always use:
`npm link (in package dir)` and `npm link [<@scope>/]<pkg>[@<version>]` which will install module on your disk only once and every additional time will just make symlink to that module.

Comment: As I am learning/playing with JS Electron apps.  Each project I set up ends up with like 50mb of node modules and in each projects a majority of the modules are the same ones used on each other.  I am not sure if this is considered command line use or not?  The modules are included into the project JS file and then I run `npm start` on the project to launch the demo app windows

Comment: @JasonDavis Now electron-quick-start node_modules is 123MB, and empty ES6/7 project with Electron Forge is 315MB... Did you find a way to move node_modules globally?

Answer (score 2):

Even if this thread is old, the correct answer is not mentioned here, so let me update this for future readers:

Yes, there is something that solved exactly what you just described.

It's called PNPM: https://pnpm.js.org/motivation

Basically it executes all npm commands normally, but using `pnpm install` instead of `npm install` will install all npm modules into a global folder once and then link your current project's node_modules to that global location.

So the next time another project needs package X, PNPM will first check if that pacakge already exists in the global location and if it already exists, it will only link to that folder again.

This way every npm package will only exist once on your drive and you prevend duplicattions.